# Is it possible to use some CSS class to use insted of $ symbol in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Actually I have added a View (ascx) in my project and in that I added a jquery for showing Calendar as following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var FromDate = $("#FromDate");
    var ToDate = $("#ToDate");
    ValidateDate(FromDate, ToDate, "yy-mm-dd");
});     
</script>
```

and in my project we are using `$` symbol for currency for that we have created one css class, now when I am running my application it is getting conflicted and giving error, `Microsoft JScript runtime error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object`

It's working fine with ASPX View but I can't use aspx because I am using partial view which needs ascx for my project.

someone please help me with some solution.

Comment: See more about conflicts here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Sounds like you haven't referenced JQuery library.

Comment: as @speti43 says it sounds as if your jquery library may not be referenced or it could be referenced after your view (ie at the end of your body) which means that it hasn't been loaded when you are trying to call the above function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Normally in your code you can use `$` as a replacement for `jQuery`, calling `noConflict()` will removes the association between the `$` and the `jQuery` function. So you can then use another JavaScript library that also shortens to `$` without conflicts.

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of
>   $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

You can call `noConflict()` and create a totally new alias to use, like that:

```
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQ(document).ready(function () {
    var FromDate = jQ("#FromDate");
    var ToDate = jQ("#ToDate");
    ValidateDate(FromDate, ToDate, "yy-mm-dd");
});
```

[jQuery - Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $ without having a conflict with your previous $ function
you can do that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function ($){
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var FromDate = $("#FromDate");
        var ToDate = $("#ToDate");
        ValidateDate(FromDate, ToDate, "yy-mm-dd");
     });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

The Wrapper function added will execute automatically keeping a reference to jquery as $
without conflicting with the old $ before that